# Prove that $\frac{2(\pi(p)-2)}{p-1} \leq 0.6$ for all prime numbers $p \geq 31$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $f(p) = \frac{2(\pi(p)-2)}{p-1}$ where $\pi$ is the prime counting function, prove that $f(p) \leq 0.6$ for all prime numbers $p \geq 31$.

Below are some examples of $f(p)$.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, removing multiples of $2,3,5$ between $n+1$ and $n+30$ allows you to bound $\pi(n+30)\leq \pi(n)+8$ for $n>5$, and $\frac{16}{30}<0.6$.  So it remains to check $2\pi(n)-2\leq0.6\times(n-1)$ for $31\leq n\leq 60$ explicitly.

Comment: Thank you for yor response. I unfortunately cannot follow it. Can you provide more details? Thanks.

Comment: We are going to show $2(\pi(p)-2)/(p-1)<0.6$ holds for all integers $p\geq 31$, not just primes.  Being nonmultiples of 2, 3 or 5 is a necessary but not sufficient condition for being a prime > 5.  So $\pi(n+30)\leq\pi(n)+8$ for $n>5$ (in fact also for $n=5$ too).  Check that it does give the induction step (that is what the $16/30<0.6$ is doing if you check what the induction step from $n$ to $n+30$ needs), so all you have to do is to fill in the base case(s).

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\phi(30)=8$ so among $30$ consecutive integers only $8$ are coprime to $30$ and thus cannot be prime (unless $p=2$, $3$ or $5$). Therefore we have $\pi(n)-3 <\frac{8}{30}n$, can you finish from here?